# Unable to grant admin permissions Google IAM & Admin

Tags: google-workspace, google-iam

Trying to create a Project in the Google cloud platform. However, I am unable to due to not having permission to create projects in this location.

I currently have no projected created. So when I try to add myself or another user to the Google IAM & Admin page, it will not allow me because it says I do not have any projects to select.

Is there another way to enable Organization Administrator and Project Creator for Google IAM?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a Project you should have the proper permissions, mentioned in [Creating a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project):

> To create a project, you must have the ´resourcemanager.projects.create´ permission. This permission is included in the Project Creator ´roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator´ role, which is granted by default to the entire domain of a new organization and to free trial users. For information on how to grant individuals the role and limit organization-wide access, see the Managing Default Organization Roles page.

Given this, you should ask your Organization administrator to grant your user this Role.

You can create a project through the gCloud SDK:

> To create a new project, use the gcloud projects create command:

```
gcloud projects create PROJECT_ID
```

> Where ´PROJECT_ID´ is the ID for the project you want to create. A project ID must start with a lowercase letter, and can contain only ASCII letters, digits, and hyphens, and must be between 6 and 30 characters.

> To create a project with an organization or a folder as parent, use the --organization or --folder flags. As a resource can only have one parent, only one of these flags can be used:

```
gcloud projects create PROJECT_ID --organization=ORGANIZATION_ID

gcloud projects create PROJECT_ID --folder=FOLDER_ID
```